# How a computer understands the difference between a binary for a decimal and same binary for a character?

Tags: binary, ascii, number-formatting

I will ask the question by example.

If I type 33 on my keyboard, it is converted to 100001 for the processor of computer.
If I type ! (exclamation mark) on my keyboard, its again converted to 33 and hence converted to 100001

My question is: How a computer understands that first 100001 was for 33 and second 100001 was for exclamation mark. How it is differed internally?

How same binary representation is shown on output screen as 2 different outputs in terms of 33 and ! mark?

Comment: Information is "data" plus "context". In both situations the end data is the same, but the program you're interacting with understands the context.

Comment: For any given byte some code on your computer must know if it's meant to represent a number, a character or something else (maybe a color?). Without that knowledge these are equivalent and can't be distinguished. For example if your computer sees a file called `helloworld.txt` it can reasonably assume that the content is meant to be text. If it's `helloworld.jpg` then the content has to be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine an application (like in your example) that has two input fields. One input field is meant to contain a number between 0 and 255 (inclusive) and the other is meant to hold a single character (let's say as defined in ASCII, so it can be in the range of 0 to 127).

When you indicate that you're done entering data in one of those fields (be it by pressing enter or pushing some button on-screen) then the program will take the input text and parse it into the desired format.

So for the first input field, it will calculate the result (let's say you entered `33`, so the result is the number 33) and it'll store it in some memory location X. The byte at memory location X is now 33.

For the second input field, there's no conversion necessary, it simply takes the first (and/or only) character of the input and transfers it to a memory location Y. Assuming you've entered `!` the byte at memory location Y is now also 33.

If you looked at the memory at the locations X and Y and had no further information, you wouldn't know what the 33 in each case represents: it's just a number, it has no "flag" or meta-data that tells you how to interpret it.

But the program that *wrote* them there knows: It knows that the value at memory location X is to be interpreted as a number and the value at memory location Y is to be interpreted as a character. That's written in the *structure* or the code itself.

In theory one could have some kind of *tagged storage* where together with any given piece of information you also have some meta-data that explains *what* that information is.

Many OO-systems actually implement this in a way: when data of an object is stored in memory, it often <sup>*</sup> contains a header that describes the *type* of the object. For example in OpenJDK the object header will contain a reference to the class of the object. In this case (if you are able to interpret the header) you can *tell* how each part of the following memory region is to be interpreted, by looking at the class description.

<sup>* but not always, OO systems without runtime type information exist.</sup>

Comment: Makes sense by your very clear description. Thanks